# Subquery, inside Select, not applying Order By to underlying query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

In the following linq statement (in .net 4.5) I'm trying to do a left join on two tables, then take only the first row of each join based upon a sort done on the second table.

```
using (var context = new TestEntities())
{
    var items = ctx.FirstTables
                   .GroupJoin(
                       ctx.SecondTables,
                       first => first.IntJoin,
                       second => second.IntJoin,
                       (firstTableRow, secondTableRows) 
                           => new { firstTableRow, secondTableRows })
                   .Select(
                       result => new
                                     {
                                         result.firstTableRow.IntJoin,
                                         NewWanted = result.secondTableRows
                                                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sort)
                                                        .Select(x => (int?)x.Wanted)
                                                        .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
                                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                                     });
}
```

However the `OrderByDescending` call is not being applied to the second table, so the `Wanted` column always returns the value from the first column in the database.

So given the following table values

FirstTable:

```
IntJoin
0
1
2
null
```

SecondTable:

```
IntJoin || Sort || Wanted
0          0       1
0          1       2
0          2       3
1          0       6
1          1       5
1          2       4
null       0       7
null       1       9
null       2       8
```

I would expected to get the following list:

```
IntJoin || NewWanted
0          3
1          4
2          null
null       8
```

What I get however is this

```
IntJoin || NewWanted
0          1
1          6
2          null
null       7
```

And get the following in EntityFrameworkCore running in .net Core 2.0.1

```
IntJoin || NewWanted
0          3
1          4
2          null
null       null
```

So Entity Framework in .net Framework is ignoring the `OrderByDescending` call and Entity Framework Core isn't (.net Core seems to not be able to handle the null comparison. I'm not using core and only created an example to test the difference, so that issue is best left to (or might be answered in) another question)

I've tried all this in .net 4.5 and 4.7 (using Entity Framework 6.2.0), .net Core 2.0 (using Entity Framework Core 2.0.1) with Microsoft Sql Server 2008 and 2016 and achieved the same results.

I know I could probably call a `.ToList()` between the `GroupJoin` and `Select` but this is part of a larger query and performing the query in memory would be very prohibitive.

I've also tried calling `OrderBy` as well as different values, including the `Sort` column in the `Select` without any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've hit (one of the few compared to EF Core) EF6 query translation bug since the generated SQL query has no `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [Project3].[IntJoin] AS [IntJoin],
    [Project3].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Extent1].[IntJoin] AS [IntJoin],
        (SELECT TOP (1)
            [Project1].[Wanted] AS [Wanted]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT
                [Extent2].[Wanted] AS [Wanted]
                FROM [dbo].[SecondTable] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[IntJoin] = [Extent2].[IntJoin]) OR (([Extent1].[IntJoin] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[IntJoin] IS NULL)) ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[FirstTable] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project3]
```

The solution is to move `DefaultIfEmpty` before `OrderByDescending` (basically following the "regular" LINQ left outer join pattern:

```
NewWanted = result.secondTableRows
                .DefaultIfEmpty() // <--
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sort)
                .Select(x => (int?)x.Wanted)
                //.DefaultIfEmpty()
                .FirstOrDefault()
```

which translates to:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [Extent1].[IntJoin] AS [IntJoin],
    [Limit1].[Wanted] AS [Wanted]
    FROM  [dbo].[FirstTable] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project2].[Wanted] AS [Wanted]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Project1].[Sort] AS [Sort],
            [Project1].[Wanted] AS [Wanted]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT
                [Extent2].[Sort] AS [Sort],
                [Extent2].[Wanted] AS [Wanted]
                FROM [dbo].[SecondTable] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[IntJoin] = [Extent2].[IntJoin]) OR (([Extent1].[IntJoin] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[IntJoin] IS NULL)) ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[Sort] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
```

and produces the desired result.